# Opening links that are in an iFrame(no control over the child site) in the parent window

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, iframe, uiwebview

I am making an app for a website, and I need to include a certain part of the website, which I have done with an `iframe`. I have turned that into my own site, and everything works fine with the web view and such. The problem is the links are opened inside the `iframe`, whereas I want the page to fill the web view. I cannot modify the links themselves, as they are not on my site; only the script is.

I have tried inserting `target="_top"`, `blank`, and `parent`, but nothing seems to be working. Here is a snippet of the HTML I am using. (I have changed the URL, by the way.)

How should I go about fixing this?  Should it be fixed through Xcode, or through the script?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

     <style type="text/css">
     #container{
     width:380px;
     height:4300px;
     border:0px solid #000; 
     overflow:hidden;
     margin:auto;
     border:none;
     }
     #container iframe {
     width:380px;
     height:4880px;
     margin-left:-6px;
     margin-top:-398px;   
     border:none;
     }
   </style>
  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <iframe src="http://www.Google.com/" scrolling="no">
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you're saying currently the site opens in your designated UIWebView within your app currently... but you'd prefer it in the mobile Safari or full screen within your app? (with a navigation bar still, so they are browsing fully but in-app still)

Comment: @Krypton    There is a portion of a website I had to use on my iPhone.  So I made a site with an iFrame, that just limits it to that selection.  The portion is a news section, which I wish to use i the webView.  I have got that working, and it looks great.  Problem is though, when you click a link, it is still in the iFrame, and since there are restrictions on the iFrame, the site is distorted.  I need to load the URL itself, and not IN the iFrame.  How should I go about making the link open in a new window?  As this would also fix the problem.

Comment: Okay right - I am in a similar dilemma here myself with an app I am working on. Both Safari and our apps utlise a UIWebView to display the content, and as the pages we want to view were made for computer viewing, the UIWebView resizes it to fit the iPhone screen so it looks nasty. I am not aware of any fix for this - unless you edit your HTML to work nicely with a mobile device; so you will want to set the fonts in a larger text size, and maybe frame the page for the device you are targeting.

Comment: I got my setup working, using iFrame, and the code I have, as I only needed one portion.  I just need links to not open in the iFrame itself, but in the window.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Sorry - it might just be me, but can you clarify what you are trying to do... your iFrame will be inside a web view inside the app, and you want those iFrame links to keep working in the web view? What is window?

Comment: Forget about the app portion for now.  I have a website, and in that website is an iframe. The iFrame is a portion of another website.  When I click links in the iFrame, it opens them within the iframe, when I really just want it to treat it as an actual link, and not as an iFrame.  I do not have access to the links, so I have to do it somehow within the parent.  Ideas?

Comment: There's always ways to access links... surely? Sounds like you want the links clicked on to respond to the whole area available instead of within the multiple iFrames? You can change the src of the parent frame to whatever the link requested was - if you can access it at least.

Comment: Is there any other way I could contact you?  If I were talking to you through something else, I would be able to show you my work/examples.  Which would be much easier.  And the website in the iFrame, is an external website.  The links are on that website, and I need it so when you click those links it will open them in the parent window.  Do you have AIM?

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do now; whether I could concoct a solution personally I am not sure of. If you view my profile you'll find a way, but perhaps it is best for someone else to view your question as they'll likely have a better understanding on the web side of things... sorry to disappoint.

Comment: That is fine, thanks for your time and effort though.  You did help me :) I hope your problem gets solved too.

Comment: May I suggest an easier way to do this? Instead of using an iframe, why don't you use a native WebView? Because of cross-domain security restrictions, you can't modify the contents of an iframe that you don't own. But you _can_ modify the contents of a WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think jQuery can help you. You need to find all links inside your frame and add required attribute to each of them.

```
$('#yourIframe').contents().find('a').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

P.S. Don't forget to change your ifarame id (or change to class, if you like).